# How do I deploy an unpacked maven project to Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

Per the Tomcat 7 documentation...

> A web application is defined as a hierarchy of directories and files
>   in a standard layout. **Such a hierarchy can be accessed in its**
>   "**unpacked" form**", where each directory and file exists in the
>   filesystem separately, or in a "packed" form known as a Web ARchive,
>   or WAR file. **The former format is more useful during development**,
>   while the latter is used when you distribute your application to be
>   installed. (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html)

The project I'm working with is a maven project (and must stay that way).  I would like to simply put the project in my Tomcat `webapps` folder and run it from source (without doing a maven deploy) while I'm debugging/developing it.  For production, I will use maven to build a war file for deployment.  Is it possible to run a maven project from source? (without compiling to a war file?)

Comment: The IDE will normally do this for you. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse & Maven and I currently have a Maven run configuration that deploys to a war file in the tomcat `webapps` folder.

Comment: you can create a war using maven... look a this: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html

Comment: In Eclipse, have you added Tomcat as a server via *New -> Server* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Muel commented, you have to compile the files first, once you have all your files compiled, you can put it in any folder inside web apps (even ROOT, but should be empty), the app will use the folder name as context path (Except for ROOT that deploys in "/")